# How to create UIButton connections in Xcode6 using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

Can any one explain me , how can we set action for UIButton, which is created in swift storyboard. In iOS 7 we can connect directly by drag and drop by selecting touchupinside but in Xcode6 i am not able to find that.

Comment: It's still the same technique. Just drag the connection from the button into the .swift file and select "Action" as connection type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still there. Don't forget to add a custom class for the controller:

[image]

Then you'll be able to control-drag from storyboard **to the class definition** in swift file (because there is no @interface section in swift) or to the yellow controller icon in the interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you hold the "ctrl" key? hold "ctrl" and drag.